# Visual Studio 2015 SSIS Options Missing in Choose Toolbox Items

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis

I've just stared working with SSIS in Visual Studio 2015 and I have no issue getting a package design started and I can see the **SSIS toolbox**. However some items are missing from the toolbox.

The normal recommendation to fixing this is to into Choose Toolbox items and add the missing control.

However when I do this I find that SSIS Data Flow Items and SSIS Control Flow items are not available as tabs.

Does anyone have a remedy for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that can cause this problem:

1- there are some visual studio add-ins that cause this issue. Try running visual studio in safemode abd try to add items. Just run this command

```
devenv.exe /safemode
```

2- your visual studio sql data tools installation is corrupted try repairing it.

Comment: Thanks for this - I've tried these but no luck. I have a feeling that my issues ins SQL server data tools not adding to the GAC. I'm looking into the best way to do this now